# jQuery selector does not work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say I've a few

```
<p> Hello </p>
<p> Hello </p>
<p> Hello </p>
<p> Hello </p>
```

I want to replace one "Hello" by "Good bye".

```
So => $('p')[2].html('Good Bye');
```

It is not working why? Why should I must use the eq: selector?

It's working when I do that

```
$('p:eq(3)').html('Good bye')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to use `html()` method `with javascript object` which is supposed to be used with jQuery object, you can use `innerHTML`  with javascript object so you need this,

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Bdhht/)**

```
$('p')[2].innerHTML = 'Good Bye';
```

Answer (score 2):

When you use brackets you are not receiving a jQuery object, you receive the original javascript object, for example if you want yo use the submit javascript function from a form you should use

```
jQuery('form')[0].submit()
```

Answer (score 2):

js object doesn't have html() method,only JQ object has.

so ,you can do it like this:

```
$('p').eq(2).html('hello,I am Chinese');
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you could use:

```
$( $('p')[2]).html('Good Bye');
```